# Is there a way to upgrade a military station's defence platform?

Tags: stellaris

As time marches on, so does progress and the military station that was built for our previous glorious leader is getting a bit obselite.

Is there a way to upgrade its components?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [stellaris wiki](http://www.stellariswiki.com/Construction#Defense_platforms), the answer is no.

The only alternate solution is to scrap the old one, and build a new one, in the same place.

Comment: This used to be the right answer, but support for upgrading stations is now part of the core game.

Answer (score 12):

Looks like we can upgrade stations now, as of the Asimov beta release.  I am not sure whether this is new in Asimov or if it was added in Clarke, as neither set of patch notes makes specific mention of it.  However it does say in the Asimov release notes that AI controlled empires and sector managers will now upgrade stations automatically.

To upgrade manually, select the station and click the upgrade icon.  This icon should be grayed out if you don't have the resources yet. I've confirmed that automatic upgrades work for sectors as well, and is typically done very quickly.

Comment: When you say "I think", exactly which piece of information are you expressing uncertainty about? Whether the change occurred, or whether it was part of the Asimov update?

Comment: @DCShannon - mainly about whether it was specifically part of Asimov.  You can definitely upgrade stations in the Asimov beta.  I remember trying to upgrade stations before and was unable, but I can't remember if it was before or after the Clarke release.  I'll edit my answer to clarify this.